# The Csv file is being read into my ReadCsvFile method, but is then not being passed to where I parse it (TinyCsvParser)

Tags: c#, .net, csv

So I'm having my web-page offer to upload a CSV file with pertinent data for my users to update their cart items. So the file is uploaded, parsed in real time, and then the cart is updated on the spot; thus allowing me not having to save their file anywhere. However, after the CSV is read in my ReadCsvFile() method, the data is not being passed to where I need to parse it. The 'result' variable in the Debug is equal to 0.

In my line containing -> var result = csvParser.ReadFromString(csvReaderOptions, ReadCsvFile().ToString()).ToList();

^^I have tried taking out the '.ToString' and then placing 'await' in front of 'ReadCsvFile()'. An error then pop up in debug saying there is a 'CsvFileMapping Error = ,'

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                CsvParserOptions csvParserOptions = new CsvParserOptions(true, ',');
                CsvReaderOptions csvReaderOptions = new CsvReaderOptions(new[] {Environment.NewLine});
                CsvFileMapping csvMapper = new CsvFileMapping();
                CsvParser<CsvData> csvParser = new CsvParser<CsvData>(csvParserOptions, csvMapper);

                var result = csvParser.ReadFromString(csvReaderOptions, ReadCsvFile().ToString()).ToList();
                foreach (var i in result)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File could not be read");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }


            return RedirectToAction("Index", "CartsMvc");
        }
```

```
[BindProperty]
        public IFormFile UploadedFile{get; set;}

        public async Task<string> ReadCsvFile()
        {

            string results;

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(UploadedFile.OpenReadStream()))
            {
                results = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }

            return results;

        }
```

Comment: I have the Console.WriteLine(i) foreach loop in my OnPostAsync method because before I get to updating my cart, I just want to start seeing the data be passed thru first. Just to clarify!

Comment: Try adding this before the call `var csv = await ReadCsvFile();` then pass in the var `csv` to the `csvParser.ReadFromString` method.

Comment: @SimonWilson is this what you had in mind?    `var csv = await ReadCsvFile();
                var result = csvParser.ReadFromString(csvReaderOptions, csv.ToList().ToString());`

Comment: @SimonWilson This got my data passed into my OnPostAsync(), so thank you! If you want to copy my code that is above this comment, I'll mark it as an answer! thanks again

Comment: `csv.ToList().ToString()` should not be required, `csv` is a string now you awaited it.

Comment: @SimonWilson you are correct, I had deleted the .ToString after walking thru the debugger and seeing it as unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @SimonWilson, we were able to correct the problem of getting the CSV data read into my OnPostAsync() method.

```
var csv = await ReadCsvFile();
var result = csvParser.ReadFromString(csvReaderOptions, csv).ToList();
```

These two lines replace the one line which was as follows

```
var result = csvParser.ReadFromString(csvReaderOptions, ReadCsvFile().ToString()).ToList();
```